# How to convert cell diagram to a chemical equation?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, transition-metals

How would one convert on the right side of the cell diagram:

$$\ce{Zn(s) | Zn^2+(aq) || MnO4-(aq), Mn^2+(aq), H+(aq) | Pt(s)}$$

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{Zn(s) &-> Zn^2+(aq)} \tag{ox}\\
\ce{MnO4-(aq) &-> Mn^2+(aq)}\tag{red}
\end{align}
$$

Obviously, one would then balance and combine the half-equations. I just need to know if the unbalanced half-equations are correct.

Comment: You can find useful  [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).  

See also [upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The reduction «or something like that» does not make sense.  _Most often_ classes introducing redox chemistry  refer to the reduction of permanganate $\ce{MnO^-_4}$ into $\ce{Mn^{2+}}$ _if_ the reaction is conducted in acidic media.  Reductions in neuter, and basic media yield other products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant $\ce{MnO^-4}$ and not $\ce{MnO^{4-}}$, your reduction half reaction is incorrect. Because according to your equation $\ce{Mn^{2+}}$ is being oxidised to $\ce{MnO^-4}$ rather than being reduced.

The correct half cell reactions would be:

$$
\ce{Zn -> Zn^{2+} + 2e-}\\
\ce{MnO^-4 + 8H+ + 5e- -> Mn^{2+} + 4H2O}\\
$$

And so the overall balanced reaction would come out to be:

$$\ce{5Zn + 2MnO^-4 + 16H+ -> 5Zn^{2+} + 2Mn^{2+} + 8H2O}$$

Comment: It was typed wrong on the tutorial sheet and I did not spot the error before submitting the question. The corrected cell diagram makes far more sense; before it was conflicting against cell diagram convention.

Comment: To clarify: The H+ on the RHS of the cell diagram simply means the reaction is being performed under acidic conditions?

Comment: @jseissmann Yes, it shows that the medium is acidic.

Comment: @jseissmann For a reaction equation to be balanced, the number of atoms on the right, and on the left hand side must be ... equal. Simultaneously, the sum of the charges on the left must equate the sum of the charges on the right hand side of the arrow, too. The reduction, as written by you: $\ce{ MnO^-4 -> Mn^{2+} }$. Left hand side: four atoms of oxygen, right hand side: none; thus not balanced.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar This is true, I forgot to set the `@` sign; the comment was to the OP.

Comment: @Buttonwood I am aware they are unbalanced - I simply wanted to check that my translation of the cell diagram to the unbalance half-equations was correct as the H+ on the RHS threw me. I can balance half-equations just fine and therefore didn't need full answers on that part